# mod_pagespeed not loads the static files to the cache folder

Tags: mod-pagespeed

Hi I have started exploring PageSpeed module in Apache Httpd. I have used ModPagespeedLoadFromFile for doing hotfixes. Is it correct? Or do we have any other option the hotfixes of static files using PageSpeed.

The problem is while using ModPagespeedLoadFromFile, only the files under the ModPagespeedLoadFromFile are cached in ModPagespeedFileCachePath. The rest of the static files fetched from the server are not cached at ModPagespeedFileCachePath.

Kindly anyone correct me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "hotfixes"?

But assuming that you mean that rewritten resources are immediately updated when you make updates to the original resource? That is a feature of LoadFromFile, you can also use [cache flushing](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#flush_cache) for that.

I don't understand the FileCachePath half of your question at all. What is the problem that you observe? Files not being rewritten? Broken files?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

What i meant for hotfix is, I am just updating the static files and without redeploy/restart the server i want to reflect the changes immediately to the user screen.

Comment: **Scenario**: All static files are in server which will be routed via httpd. mod_pagespeed is configured for caching/compression of static files from the server. I have enabled LoadFromFile in pagespeed.conf. I have loaded one or more static files in the LoadFromFile folder with some updates(which i mean hotfix). 

**Result**: The hotfix files only cached to the PageSpeed cache folder. The rest of the static files from the server are not cached to the PageSpeed cache folder and they were served as a Http fetch call to the server.

Comment: Yes, I understand. mod_pagespeed will cache your files for as long as you set the cache headers. So if you want changes to be immediately updated, you need to either use LoadFromFile or use the cache flushing I mentioned. Does that do what you want?